# Passing datetime to a stored procedure & add a 1 sec to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, stored-procedures

There are two things here i want to accomplish.

- List I want to pass a datetime into my stored procedure in the following format ('2007-05-28 00:00:00'), but that doesn't seem to work unless i use {ts '2007-05-28 00:00:00'}
- The next thing is I want to increase the @SEAL_DATE by a second so it can be used to check the dates between the entered time and a second after.

Thanks in advance

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getSealRecordDate]  (@SEAL_DATE DATETIME)
    AS
-- Declare variables


 SELECT DISTINCT "FGFSTRANSFERS"."CONSIDERATION", "FGFSTRANSFERS"."AMOUNT_TRANSFER", "FGFSTRANSFERS"."DATE", "FGFSTransferDetails"."TRANSFER_ID", "FGFSTRANSFERS"."TRANSFER_ID", "FGFSTRANSFERS"."Curr", "FGFSTransferDetails"."CURR", "FGFSCUSTOMERS"."CMF_NAME_1", "FGFSCUSTOMERS"."CMF_NAME_2"
 FROM   ("FGFSInvestment"."dbo"."FGFSTransferDetails" "FGFSTransferDetails" INNER JOIN "FGFSInvestment"."dbo"."FGFSTRANSFERS" "FGFSTRANSFERS" ON "FGFSTransferDetails"."TRANSFER_ID"="FGFSTRANSFERS"."TRANSFER_ID") INNER JOIN "FGFSInvestment"."dbo"."FGFSCUSTOMERS" "FGFSCUSTOMERS" ON "FGFSTRANSFERS"."CUSTODIAN"="FGFSCUSTOMERS"."CMF_ACCOUNT"
 WHERE  ("FGFSTRANSFERS"."DATE">= @SEAL_DATE AND "FGFSTRANSFERS"."DATE"<{ts '2007-05-28 00:00:01'})

 -- EXEC getSealRecordDate {ts '2007-05-28 00:00:00'}
```

**Pseudo-SQL**
so it should be like: WHERE  ("FGFSTRANSFERS"."DATE">= @SEAL_DATE AND "FGFSTRANSFERS"."DATE"< @SEAL_DATE+ 1 sec ) <-- Something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DATEADD(second, 1, @SEAL_DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [How Does Between Work With Dates In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-)

use dateadd to add a second

```
select dateadd(second,1,'20090625 00:00:00.000')
```

Answer (score 0):

For your second part, use DATEADD

DateAdd (second, 1, @DateVariable)